# AzureDevOps Pipeline fails on creating database in Djano test

Tags: django, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have been trying to build an Azure DevOps Pipeline for CI/CD for my Django project. The code is being pulled from a github repo (and is actually deployed already on Azure app service). However, when I run the test on the Pipeline I get the following error when it runs `python manage.py test`:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...

pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
```

I tried extensively to [whitelist Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-import?view=azure-devops#azure-devops-services-ips) but the error has persisted. How can I resolve this so that the Pipeline can run tests for CI/CD?

Comment: Not get your latest information, are the answers below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

Which agent are you using? Hosted agent or self-hosted agent?

If you are using hosted agent, since we are running the code in the pipeline via hosted agent, we should add [hosted agent IP addresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#networking) to the whitelist instead of Azure DevOps Services IPs. The whitelist Azure DevOps you used is Azure DevOps Service IP. About hosted agent IP, we publish a [weekly JSON file](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519) listing IP ranges for Azure data centers, broken out by region. To obtain the complete list of possible IP ranges for your agent, you must use the IP ranges from all of the regions that are contained in your geography.

If you are using self-hosted agent. Please check your local agent server IP and then add it.